# Uniform and $2k_F$ density operators in 1+1D bosonization

Tags: bosonization

Consider the standard operator identities in 1+1D bosonization
$$\psi^\dagger_{L,R}\sim e^{i(\phi\pm\theta)},\\\rho(x)\equiv\psi^\dagger_L\psi_L+\psi^\dagger_R\psi_R=\frac{1}{\pi}\partial_x\theta.$$

I wonder how can one derive the second line (density operator) from the first line, maybe using some commutator properties of $\phi$ and $\theta$ fields.

This question is partially motivated by the identification of the $2k_F$ density operator as 
$$\psi_L^\dagger\psi_R=e^{2i\theta},$$
which apparently utilizes the first equation above. Here, the drastically differnt forms of uniform density $\rho_x$ and $2k_F$ density intrigue me.